# Should I get a response when beeping two GND pins on a CPLD?

Tags: programmable-logic

I have an Altera CPLD, 5M570ZT100I5N (100 pins, Quad-Flat-Package) mounted in a socket adapter to get access to the pins. I try to beep two GND pins on the same edge of the package, but get no response. Is this an indicator that something is wrong with my socket adapter ? BTW, the CPLD is not programmed, nor has any power connected to it. I would still expect any two GND pins on the same IO-bank to be connected. Am I wrong ?

Comment: what is `beep`?

Comment: @jsotola Continuity test.

Comment: continuity test using what kind of a device?

Comment: multimeter buzzer

Answer (score 3):

Many chips do not have internally connected GND pins. This is frequently done in order to allow a separate analog and digital ground and to allow decoupling isolation. The same is true on VDDs as well.

Comment: Why does Altera not document this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an indicator that something is wrong with my socket adapter

probably, YES. are any other pins open?

Interesting but hopefully not relevant...

> **Programmable Ground Pins**
>
> Each unused I/O pin on MAX V devices can be used as an additional ground pin.
> This programmable ground feature does not require the use of the associated LEs in
> the device. In the Quartus II software, unused pins can be set as programmable GND
> on a global default basis or they can be individually assigned. Unused pins also have
> the option of being set as tri-stated input pins.

[From the Altera (now Intel) MAX V Device Handbook](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/max-v/max5_handbook.pdf)